# Generic ArrayList

Tags: java, generics

Can anyone recommend improvements to the compress() method?

```
public class ArrayList<E>  {

private Object[] array;
public static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 20;
private int size = 0;

public ArrayList(){
    this(DEFAULT_SIZE);
}

public ArrayList(int size){
    array = new Object[size];
}

public void add(E element){
    ensureCapacity();
    array[size++] = element;
}

public E remove(int index){
    if(index>=size || index < 0 ){throw new RuntimeException("Invalid index");}
    E element = (E) array[index];
    array[index] = null;
    --size;
    compress();
    return element;
}

public E get(int index){
    if(index > size){throw new RuntimeException("Invalid index");}
    E element = (E) array[index];
    return element;
}

public int size(){
    return this.size;
}

private void ensureCapacity(){
    if(size < array.length){ return;}
    resize();
}

private void resize(){
    Object[] temp = new Object[array.length*2];
    copy(array,temp);
    array = temp;
}

private void copy(Object[] src, Object[] dest){
    if(dest.length< src.length){throw new RuntimeException(src+ " cannot be copied into "+dest);}
    for(int i=0;i<src.length; i++){
        dest[i] = src[i];
    }   
}

private void compress(){
    int skipCount =0;
    for(int i=0;i < size && i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]==null){
            ++skipCount;                
        }
        array[i]=array[i+skipCount];
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are actually doing? Are you, knowingly that `ArrayList` exists, making your own implementation for fun? Why does it not implement the `List<E>` interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### General

There are a few things in here....

- You allow users to add a null value in the `add()` method, but you will then 'compress' it later if you remove something.
- you have an off-by-one error on the `get()` (but not `remove()` ) methods... it should be `>= size`, and not `> size`.
- `compress()` is only called from `remove()`. I would recommend removing the compress() method and making remove just compress 1 value:

  ```
  public E remove(int index){
      if(index>=size || index < 0 ){throw new RuntimeException("Invalid index");}
      E element = (E) array[index];
      --size;
      System.arraycopy(array, index + 1, array, index, size - index);
      array[size] = null;
      return element;
  }
  ```

  Alternatively, pass in an int value to the compress method.

  If you do the above you will correctly support null values.
- Although it is tempting, don't call your class ArrayList.... it competes with the standard class name, and will produce problems. Use something like 'MyArrayList'.

### Generics

What you have right now is fine with respect to the Generics.

If you want to be a bit more correct, you can use a Class-type initializer, and use that to create correctly typed arrays, and avoud the generic `(T)array[index]` casting later.... but that is a pain, and requires passing `Class<T> clazz` in as the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

1. I agree with *@rolfl*, that `System.arraycopy` is better but about the following code:

   > ```
   > private void copy(Object[] src, Object[] dest){
   >     if(dest.length< src.length){throw new RuntimeException(src+ " cannot be copied into "+dest);}
   >     for(int i=0;i<src.length; i++){
   >         dest[i] = src[i];
   >     }   
   > }
   > ```

   If `dest.length` bigger than `src.length` you get an exception with the following message:

   ```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: [Ljava.lang.Object;@1318e59 cannot be copied into [Ljava.lang.Object;@787ee7
   ```

   It's not very useful, I'd rather put the size of the arrays to the message.
2. > ```
   > for (int i = 0; i < size && i < array.length; i++) {
   > ```

   I think the following would be a little bit easier to read:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(size, array.length); i++) {
   ```
3. > ```
   > private Object[] array;
   > ```

   I'd rename array to `data` to reflect its purpose.
4. `remove` check negative indexes:

   ```
   if (index >= size || index < 0) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Invalid index");
   }
   ```

   `get` doesn't:

   ```
   if (index > size) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Invalid index");
   }
   ```

   It would be more user-friendly to check that in both method. You could create a common `checkIndex()` method to remove the duplication. Furthermore, putting the invalid index into the exception message would be useful.